# When running the app without debugging in VSCode, the console still appears in debug mode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

We can run flutter app from VSCode in debug mode (F5) or without debbugging (Ctrl+F5).
Debugging is usefull for development and when it runs in the debug mode the console displays

> Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...

Nevertheless, when it runs without debugging the debug console again displays

> Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...

Why does VSCode display that it is running in debug mode even though the app was launched without debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug mode here is how Flutter is running your app, it's not related with Visual Studio Code.

There are three modes of running a Flutter application: debug (optimized for development), profile (optimized for debugging performance) and release (optimized for production).

If you want to run it on release mode, run in your command line

```bash
flutter run --release
```

See [Flutter's build modes](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes) for more information.

Comment: Does it mean `flutter run --release` is equivalent of `Ctrl+F5` in VSCode?

Comment: By default, both `F5` (VSCode's debug mode) and `Ctrl+F5` (VSCode's run mode) executes `flutter run --debug`. The difference between `F5` and `Ctrl+F5` is that with the former you can set breakpoints inside your code and executing it step by step, while with the latter the application runs without being interrupted. If you want to run `flutter run --release` instead by pressing `F5` or `Ctrl+F5`, you can modify your *launch.json* configuration file as described [here](https://dartcode.org/docs/running-flutter-apps-in-profile-or-release-modes/).

Comment: If you want better support for hot-reload, you use `--debug`. If you want better support for analyzing the performance of your application, you use `--profile`. And if you want better support for your end user, you use `--release`. You can both `F5` and `Ctrl+F5` each one of these modes, because [VSCode's debug/run](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) is not related with [Flutter's debug/profile/release](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). Let me know if I could make it clear!